# How to handle exceptions in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception

I'm trying to handle common exceptions in Spark, like a .map operation not working correctly on all elements of the data or a FileNotFound exception. I have read all the existing questions and the following two posts:

https://rcardin.github.io/big-data/apache-spark/scala/programming/2016/09/25/try-again-apache-spark.html

https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/18/exception-handling-in-apache-spark

I have tried a Try statement within the line `attributes => mHealthUser(attributes(0).toDouble, attributes(1).toDouble, attributes(2).toDouble`
so it reads `attributes => Try(mHealthUser(attributes(0).toDouble, attributes(1).toDouble, attributes(2).toDouble)`

But that won't compile; the compiler won't recognise the `.toDF()` statement later. I have also tried a Java-like Try { Catch {}} block but can't get the scope right; `df` is then not returned. Does anyone know how to do this properly? Do I even need to handle these exceptions, as the Spark framework seems to deal with a FileNotFound exception already without me adding one. But I would like to generate an error with the number of fields in the schema if the input file has the wrong number of columns, for example.

Here's the code:

```
object DataLoadTest extends SparkSessionWrapper {
/** Helper function to create a DataFrame from a textfile, re-used in        subsequent tests */
def createDataFrame(fileName: String): DataFrame = {

import spark.implicits._

//try {
val df = spark.sparkContext
  .textFile("/path/to/file" + fileName)
  .map(_.split("\\t"))
//mHealth user is the case class which defines the data schema
  .map(attributes => mHealthUser(attributes(0).toDouble, attributes(1).toDouble, attributes(2).toDouble,
        attributes(3).toDouble, attributes(4).toDouble,
        attributes(5).toDouble, attributes(6).toDouble, attributes(7).toDouble,
        attributes(8).toDouble, attributes(9).toDouble, attributes(10).toDouble,
        attributes(11).toDouble, attributes(12).toDouble, attributes(13).toDouble,
        attributes(14).toDouble, attributes(15).toDouble, attributes(16).toDouble,
        attributes(17).toDouble, attributes(18).toDouble, attributes(19).toDouble,
        attributes(20).toDouble, attributes(21).toDouble, attributes(22).toDouble,
        attributes(23).toInt))
  .toDF()
  .cache()
df
} catch {
    case ex: FileNotFoundException => println(s"File $fileName not found")
    case unknown: Exception => println(s"Unknown exception: $unknown")

}
}
```

All suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another option would be to use [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) type in scala.

For example:

```
def createDataFrame(fileName: String): Try[DataFrame] = {

try {
      //create dataframe df
      Success(df)
    } catch {
      case ex: FileNotFoundException => {
        println(s"File $fileName not found")
        Failure(ex)
      }
      case unknown: Exception => {
        println(s"Unknown exception: $unknown")
        Failure(unknown)
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, in the caller side, handle it like:

```
createDataFrame("file1.csv") match {
  case Success(df) => {
    // proceed with your pipeline
  }
  case Failure(ex) => //handle exception
}
```

This is slightly better than using Option as caller would know the reason for failure and can handle better.

Comment: What is import for Success and Failure? import scala.util.Failure or something else.

Comment: you need to import ```scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}```

Comment: I would love to use this but if I understand what your saying to need to nest your code inside where you say "// proceed with your pipeline" which isn't very practical. I would end up with very hard to read code nested many times. is there a way to hand the dataframe object if success to a variable using  a match or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Either you let the Exception be thrown out of the `createDataFrame` method (and handle it outside), or change the signature to return `Option[DataFrame]`:

```
  def createDataFrame(fileName: String): Option[DataFrame] = {

    import spark.implicits._

    try {
      val df = spark.sparkContext
        .textFile("/path/to/file" + fileName)
        .map(_.split("\\t"))
        //mHealth user is the case class which defines the data schema
        .map(attributes => mHealthUser(attributes(0).toDouble, attributes(1).toDouble, attributes(2).toDouble,
        attributes(3).toDouble, attributes(4).toDouble,
        attributes(5).toDouble, attributes(6).toDouble, attributes(7).toDouble,
        attributes(8).toDouble, attributes(9).toDouble, attributes(10).toDouble,
        attributes(11).toDouble, attributes(12).toDouble, attributes(13).toDouble,
        attributes(14).toDouble, attributes(15).toDouble, attributes(16).toDouble,
        attributes(17).toDouble, attributes(18).toDouble, attributes(19).toDouble,
        attributes(20).toDouble, attributes(21).toDouble, attributes(22).toDouble,
        attributes(23).toInt))
        .toDF()
        .cache()

      Some(df)
    } catch {
      case ex: FileNotFoundException => {
        println(s"File $fileName not found")
        None
      }
      case unknown: Exception => {
        println(s"Unknown exception: $unknown")
        None
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT: on the caller-side of createDataFrame there are several patterns. If you are processing several filenames, you can e.g. do:

```
 val dfs : Seq[DataFrame] = Seq("file1","file2","file3").map(createDataFrame).flatten
```

If you are working on a single filename, you can do:

```
createDataFrame("file1.csv") match {
  case Some(df) => {
    // proceed with your pipeline
    val df2 = df.filter($"activityLabel" > 0).withColumn("binaryLabel", when($"activityLabel".between(1, 3), 0).otherwise(1))
  }
  case None => println("could not create dataframe")
}
```

Comment: @Raphael_Roth thanks that works but then breaks the next line, which is expecting a DataFrame, not an Option[DataFrame]: `val df2 = df
        .filter($"activityLabel" > 0)
        .withColumn("binaryLabel",when($"activityLabel".between(1, 3), 0).otherwise(1))`  I have changed df2 to Option[DataFrame] but the .filter won't compile now.

Comment: @LucieCBurgess Read on how to use Option in scala, or show us the code how you use `createDataFrame`, are you iterating over filenames?

Comment: @Raphael_Roth: I tried this: `val df: DataFrame = DataLoadTest.createDataFrame(fileName).getOrElse(None)`  This is in a separate class, so I'm not reassigning df to val. I get the error:  "Expression of type Serializable doesn't confirm to expected type sql.DataFrame"

Comment: @LucieCBurgess No this does not work, you will never get a variable of type DataFrame, because you may get a None in which case you will not be able to proceed with your logic

Comment: Thanks, edit is helpful. But I don't want the pipeline within the case statement and I still can't get 'data' out as a DataFrame. The `case None => ` statement won't compile as it's of type Unit and it's expecting a DataFrame.   `val data: DataFrame = createDataFrame(fileName) match {
      case Some(data) => data  
      case None => println("Could not create DataFrame")
    }

      val df2 = data.filter($"activityLabel" > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

apply try and catch block on dataframe columns:

```
(try{$"credit.amount"} catch{case e:Exception=> lit(0)}).as("credit_amount")
```